# R matrix partition and concat

Tags: r, matrix

How can I concat the matrix in R?

I have some large matrix with:

```
> dim(land)
[1] 1760  880
```

I want something like:

```
A B C D
E F G H
```

Split in two and concat to get:

```
C D A B
G H E F
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
#reproducible matrix
land <- as.matrix(read.table(text="A B C D
                                E F G H"))
#output
cbind(land[,(ncol(land)/2+1):ncol(land)],
  land[,1:(ncol(land)/2)])

#      V3  V4  V1  V2 
#[1,] "C" "D" "A" "B"
#[2,] "G" "H" "E" "F"
```

Comment: +1. You can avoid the `cbind` too: `land[, c((ncol(land)/2+1):ncol(land), 1:(ncol(land)/2))]`.